# HTML change margin and backgroundcolor of description window in Google-Earth

Tags: html, margin, background-color, kml, google-earth

I want to display a point in Google Earth and show an associated image. For this I have created a .kml file in Python:

```
kml = simplekml.Kml()
kml.newpoint(description= '<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/be/Stadtbild_K%C3%B6ln_%2850MP%29.jpg" width="400" height="250"/><br><br><font size="+1" font color="black">Köln</font>', coords=[(6.96, 50.94, 53)])
kml.save('Cologne.kml')
```

As you can see, the window is larger than the space needed for the text.

[image]

What is the best way to adjust the window size? Do I have to use CSS? Furthermore, I would like to change the background color of this window. I know that I could use a style attribute, but I have difficulties in using it.
Help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please share a copy or sample of your KML file, so we can see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code for changing background color:

```
kml = simplekml.Kml()
kml.newpoint(description= '<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/be/Stadtbild_K%C3%B6ln_%2850MP%29.jpg" width="400" height="250" bgcolor="blue"/><br><br><font size="+1" font color="black">Köln</font>', coords=[(6.96, 50.94, 53)])
kml.save('Cologne.kml')
```

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing changes!